# Formally asking a univerity for contact information of PhD

Tags: etiquette

I'm using certain software for my research and have some questions about troubleshooting and the output it creates. All the available information (manual, website and publication) isn't very extensive and can't answer my questions. That is why I want to contact the developer (a PhD) and ask my questions directly.

The problem is that the software is a little older but is still applicable to my research (never change a winning team). That's why maintenance of the website has probably stopped and the contact information there might not be correct anymore. I tried sending an e-mail to the adress on the page but never recieved an answer. What I do know is the name of the person I'm trying to reach. A simple Google search shows that this person is working at a certain univerity.

**Question:** Is it acceptable to contact this univerity and ask for contact information of one of their employees? And what is a polite way to ask this person for help? I might imagine that this might seem a bit rude and this is not appriciated. There is an online questionboard which has been inactive for some time now (as in years). But if somebody tried to contact me about my research, I would find the interest in my work flattering. I'm a little divided on the matter.

Comment: Does this person have a University profile page? You might find their contact info there

Comment: @Landric: After searching the web some more I found out that he might be employed in the UK. I'm not sure because his personal website (with the e-mailadress I mailed but got no reaction from) says he works in Australia. So I'm not sure which info is correct

Comment: Look up his last (first author) publication. There is a good chance his contact information can be found in it. Obviously you should be very courteous in your e-mail since he is probably not obligated to supply support.

Comment: @Roland: he has indeed no obligation to help me. Your comment made me realise there is a online forum/questionboard for my kind of question. Unfortunately, it hasn't seen activity in years so I won't get help there. That's why it might be a bit rude to email this person directly. He might want to keep things related to work and things related to the software he makes separated. I edited this into my question